# is it ok to say "Please call me by Mary" or "Please call me my first name"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Ok, in [the dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/call)

> Call: 3- HAVE A NAME [transitive] to have a particular name or title,
>   or use a particular name or title for someone or something
>
> **be called something**
>
> Our son is called Matthew.
>
> The arrow that appears on the screen is called a cursor.
>
> **call somebody something**
>
> My name’s Virginia, but my friends call me Ginny.
>
> Do you want to be called Miss or Ms?
>
> **call somebody by something**
>
> I prefer to be called by my middle name.

So,

**call somebody by something*: it sounds ok to say "**Please call me by my first name**"

"**call somebody something**": it sounds ok to say "**Please call me Mary**"

it sounds strange to say "**Please call me my first name**" & "**Please call me by Mary**"

So, when to use "**call somebody by something**" & when to use "**call somebody something**"?

Answer (score 1):

I think the rule is to **call somebody *by* something** when the something is a category of names (or labels) and not a specific, proper name.

> ***They called her by her nationality.*** ("Nationality" is a type of label.)
>
> ***We did a roll call by last name.*** ("Last name" is a type of name.)

**Call somebody something** and omit the "by" when the something is a specific or proper name.

> ***They call me Ishmael.*** ("Ishmael" is a proper name.)
>
> ***What do they call her?*** ("Her" refers to a specific person.)